# MapView delegate returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapviewdelegate

I'm doing an app that I input one address in one ViewController  and this address goes to the MapView in other ViewController and add an annotation.
But when I add the address when return to the mapview the app crashes and show me that my mapview.delegate is nil.
Here is my code for the address input:

```
 @IBAction func createButtonPressed(_sender: Any) {

            guard let address = addresTxtFd.text else { return }
            guard let date = dateTxtFd.text else { return }
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString((address)) { (placemarks, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                        let location = placemark.location!
                        let latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
                        let longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
                        self.locatinService.setLocation(address: address, date: date, latidude: latitude, longitude: longitude, completion: { (success) in
                            if success {
                                let map = MapVC()
                                map.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                                self.present(map, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //                             LocationServices().dropPin()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is my mapview:

```
class MapVC: UIViewController {

//    Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var newGSButton: UIButton!
//    Variables

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationAuthorization = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    var regionRadius: Double = 1000

    let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
        configureCurrentLocation()
    }

    @IBAction func centerUserLocation(_ sender: Any) {
       centerUserCurrentLocation()
    }

    @IBAction func newGSButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if AuthService.instance.isLoggedIn
        {
            let newGs = NewGarageSaleVC()
            newGs.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
            present(newGs, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_LOGIN, sender: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Thanks all.

Comment: uhh.. it's not trying to unwrap the delegate.. Also, you "might" have undefined behaviour.. `geocodeAddressString` runs on a background thread.. not the main thread. Check if your outlets are set. Add a breakpoint on the line `mapView.delegate` and type `po mapView == nil` to see if it's set. We cannot figure out your error message for you without actually seeing the entire error message itself.

Comment: Hi Brandon, Thanks for your reply. I added the breakpoint. When the app loads the first time the mapView has a value. When I get back from other view controller the mapView is nil. Idk if I need to reload the mapview or something like that.